# Prevent slider from jumping when value is changed

Tags: javascript, css

I have a slider that live-updates the value on a label tag to the right of it. What should I do to prevent it from "jumping" when the value goes from 1-digit value to 2-digits value? How can I give the label a fixed position so that it won't change the layout:

```js
var range = document.getElementById('range');
range.addEventListener('input', rangeChange);

function rangeChange() {
  label.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```html
<label id="label">0</label>
<input id="range" type="range" value=0 min=0 max=100>
```

Comment: What if you just place the label after the input so that it displays on the right? Easiest fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either add `width: 20px;display: inline-block;` to the label.

Or

Add a wrapper around both the elements and give them `display: flex; align-items: center;` style and width to the label.

```js
var range = document.getElementById('range');
range.addEventListener('input', rangeChange);

function rangeChange() {
  label.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
<label id="label" style="width: 20px;">0</label>
<input id="range" type="range" value=0 min=0 max=100>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! btw, is label the correct tag for this purpose? Or I should use another tag?

Comment: No label seems good. Just that you need it to be inline-block for it to take width without content.

Comment: You can avoid inline-block if you use flex. ALso that way the label is centerally aligned with the slider

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Put label to right side of slider

```js
var range = document.getElementById('range');
range.addEventListener('input', rangeChange);

function rangeChange() {
  label.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```html
<input id="range" type="range" value=0 min=0 max=100>
<label id="label">0</label>
```

Option 2: Zero padding:

```js
var range = document.getElementById('range');
range.addEventListener('input', rangeChange);

function rangeChange() {
  var val = +(this.value);
  if (10 > val) {
    val = '00' + val;
  } else if (100 > val) {
    val = '0' + val;
  }
  label.innerHTML = val;
}
```

```html
<label id="label">000</label>
<input id="range" type="range" value=0 min=0 max=100>
```